# Posting a custom story to the graph API using Facebook iOS SDK 3.5

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

In iOS Facebook SDK 3.5, there is supposedly a way to create a new story with the open graph API without needing a back-end server.

The documentation/tutorials on Facebook.com only show how it is done with a back-end server, and there seems to be no working code on the internet that I can find on how to do so.

I have managed to put together the following code based on small snippets of code but it does not work:

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *event = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
            event[@"type"] = @"leaf-events:event";
            event[@"title"] = @"Adam's Birthday";

            NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject openGraphActionForPost];
            action[@"event"] = event;

            [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/leaf-events:create"
                                               graphObject:action
                                         completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                             NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                                             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.userInfo);
                                         }];
```

This code crashes and tells me:

```
2013-06-19 19:40:01.451 Events[1150:60b] Error: {
"com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey" = "<FBSession: 0x1650fe80, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0x1651dc20, appID: 474218799329968, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x16549810>, expirationDate: 4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, refreshDate: 2013-06-19 18:39:57 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(\n    \"basic_info\"\n)>";
"com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode" = 400;
"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey" =     {
    body =         {
        error =             {
            code = 3503;
            message = "(#3503) \"{\"type\":\"leaf-events:event\",\"data\":{},\"title\":\"Adam's Birthday\",\"fbsdk:create_object\":true}\" is an invalid value for property \"event\" with type \"Reference\"";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
};
}
```

Can anyone help me and provide sample code on how to do this seemingly simple task, I've been stuck on it for 2 days straight now!

Answer (score 0):

i see that this is old question - but there are still no good answers - so i hope to help smb. 
create object:

```
- (NSDictionary *)sharingDictionaryForXXX {

   return @{
    @"type" : @"app_namespace:object_name",
    @"fbsdk:create_object" : @YES,
    @"title" : "title text",
    @"url" : @"link to your site configured in app dashboard",
    @"image" : @"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png",
    @"description" : "your description",
   };
}
```

share:

```
  id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = [FBGraphObject openGraphActionForPost];
  action[@"object_name"] = [self sharingDictionaryForXXX];
  FBOpenGraphActionShareDialogParams * params = [[FBOpenGraphActionShareDialogParams alloc] init];
  params.actionType = @"app_namespace:action_name";
  params.action = action;
  params.previewPropertyName = @"object_name";

  // Show the Share dialog if available
  if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithOpenGraphActionParams:params]) {
     [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:[params action]
                                           actionType:[params actionType]
                                  previewPropertyName:[params previewPropertyName]
                                              handler:^(FBAppCall * call, NSDictionary * results, NSError * error) {
                                                 if (error) {
                                                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                                 } else {
                                                    NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                 }
                                              }];
  } else {
     // If the Facebook app isn't available, show the Feed dialog as a fallback
     [self presentWebBasedSharing];
  }
```